# Solving Higher-Order Linear Differential Equations: How to Identify Complex Roots?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having trouble identifying higher order differential equations with complex roots. Here's a simple problem from my text:

$$
\text { Solve } \frac{d^{4} y}{d x^{4}}+2 \frac{d^{2} y}{d x^{2}}+y=0
$$

Auxiliary / Characteristic equation $m^{4}+2 m^{2}+1=\left(m^{2}+1\right)^{2}=0$ has roots $m_{1}=m_{3}=i$ and $m_{2}=m_{4}=-i$. Thus we use the generalized method for Case II (repeated real roots: $y=c_{1} e^{m_{1} x}+c_{2} x e^{m_{1} x}$). From Case II the solution is:
$$
y=C_{1} e^{i x}+C_{2} e^{-i x}+C_{3} x e^{i x}+C_{4} x e^{-i x}
$$

By Euler's ($e^{i \theta}=\cos \theta+i \sin \theta$), the grouping $C_{1} e^{i x}+C_{2} e^{-i x}$ can be expressed as $x\left(c_{3} \cos x+c_{4} \sin x\right)$. Hence the general solution is
$$
y=c_{1} \cos x+c_{2} \sin x+c_{3} x \cos x+c_{4} x \sin x
$$

Q: So the three cases with regard to auxiliary / characteristic equation are:

(1) roots are real and distinct ($ b^2 - 4ac > 0 $)

(2) real and equal ($ b^2 - 4ac = 0 $)

(3) conjugate complex numbers ($b^2 - 4ac < 0$)

And this seems to be solved via the 2nd method but how if we're dealing with imaginary complex numbers here? I understand that the roots are repeated but I'm still not getting it.

EDIT: How does the quadratic apply in these cases of higher-order functions?

Comment: The three cases business defined by that discriminant only applies to second order constant coefficient DEs hence the appearance of the *quadratic equation* to solve quadratics only.

Comment: That's part of my confusion. If the quadratic applies only to quadratics how is it the text categorizes this solution as 'real and equal' roots? For which, as I understand it, $ b^2 - 4ac = 0 $ - when this formula shouldn't apply.

Comment: The context still applies, only the discriminant nonsense goes away. For any polynomial of any degree you can only have real or complex roots, and repeated or unrepeated roots. These roots are not "real and equal" they are "complex and equal" they are two independent sets of qualifications that can be mixed and matched.

Answer (score 1):

In higher dimensions it depends on the multiplicities of  roots of characteristic polynomial. It is also significant that if a complex number is a root to a polynomial  with real coefficients, so is its conjugate.